# Excel If cell is blank sum number of blank cells for a total

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to work on a formula that will help me keep track of which rev items that  are still labeled open.
The picture below shows what I mean.

I need a formula that checks if the Action Date Closed is blank and total the amount of open Revs for that specific Rev number. In the example below there is one RR2 not closed and one RR1 not closed.
I am trying to keep track of all open revs, in a pie chart and need this total column on the top to reflect  a summary of the table below.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: Have you tried any formula? Please post your attempt. Hint: you can take a look at `COUNTIFS` formula to handle this.

Comment: no I haven not im pretty lost on this one and not sure where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done through `COUNTIFS` as @shrivallabha.redij mentioned. However I wanted to give it a shot with a single formula in a single cell using Excel's O365 spilling behaviour.

With data like:

[image]

My formula in `F2`:

```
=SORT(TRANSPOSE(CHOOSE({1,2},TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A2:A6)),COUNTIFS(A2:A6,TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A2:A6)),D2:D6,""))),1,1)
```

Comment: I think I see what caused the error @Elliott1197. Since my locale is Dutch I use the semi-colon as a delimiter. The one within the `{1;2}` array hasn't yet been properly translated to a comma. Give the updated answer a shot. Note that I made this extensive formula as a form of practice. The answer to your question may as well just lay in a plain usage of `COUNTIFS`.